# Sending Data From Android To PHP Page

Tags: php, android, http, exception

I am trying sending data from android application (with emulator) to web server (a php page) nowadays. Firstly, I had tried this program with emulator and it was working. After that, I tried this program with telephone and an exception occurred :

--> IO Exception : The operation timed out.

One part of my code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:90/takeDatas.php");
try {                   
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enlem", latitude ));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("boylam", longitude ));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Toast.makeText(ReportLocationActivity.this, "Client protokol exception ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(ReportLocationActivity.this, "IO exception "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I hope you will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you connect from a browser using the same URL?

Comment: have you added the permission for internet connectivity in your android manifest?

Comment: I think the android emulator is a standalone VM and it cant reach a localhost domain.. as Guillaurne suggested, try reaching this url from your emulator web browser to narrow down your problem (which if were right is not code related..)

Comment: @Joe & Guillaume - Yes, I didn't connect http://localhost:90 from my emulator browser. What should I do for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localhost` in emulator is the emulator itself. Not sure about Windows environment, but under Linux I was able to get an access to web server on the host system from the emulator by IP `10.0.2.2` (Note: this IP is not the IP of my Linux system, but from the emulator it's accessible exactly by this IP). 
You can read more about emulator networking [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: Yes, I used 10.0.2.2:90/simpleSending.php, no connection error. Thanks.. Php error is still exist :  "Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\wamp\www\simpleSending.php on line 3"

Answer (score 1):

Yes instead of using 127.0.0.1 or http://localhost:90 , you have to use http://10.0.2.2/simpleSending.php.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/yourpage.php");

    //This is the data to send
    String MyName = "flower"; //any data to send

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


        //This is the response from a php application
        String reverseString = response;
        Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Comment: if you will use http://10.0.2.2:90/yourpage.php, no response.Instead you use ,http://10.0.2.2/yourpage.php

Comment: If I use 10.0.2.2/mypage.php , the error message is being shown on emulator screen : CPE response org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException:Not Found

Comment: first make your php code $_REQUEST, it will support both get and post. and go to browser and check it like this http://localhost/yourpage.php?action=hussain. With this, http://10.0.2.2/yourpage.php, its working fine here

Comment: Please put your php file in www folder of wampp. This "CPE response org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException" arises when file is not there. I think, it is SOLVED

Comment: @mH16- I am sorry for my delayed answer. Firstly, my php file is also in www folder of wampp. In addition, when I used localhost/mypage.php?action=hussain, I took a http error(404 Not Found), but when I used localhost:90/mypage.php?action=hussain no error on browser (niassuh is showned ). I can't understand this problem's solution.

Comment: Please change your port to 80 .Go to httpd.conf file and change it to 80 , then , you can access localhost without specifying port no.Make sure no other application like skype ,oracle or anything using 80 port

Comment: When I installed wamp server first time, I had taken an error that port 80 is already used. And then, I had changed all 80 variables to 90 in httpd.conf. But I was suspecting that localhost/mypage.php is works, i was wrong.

Comment: thats grt, the only proble with port .

Answer (score 1):

this error might get generated because of asynchronous method call.So you need to wrap that Asynchronous method in a class.
Here is the code:

```
 package com.example.asynchttppost;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText value;
        private Button btn;
        private ProgressBar pb;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                    // out of range
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
                }


        } 

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                String url= "your website url";
                //String url ="http://10.0.2.2/remoteaccess/";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }

        }
    }
```